# Perl Mechanize firefox click event gets script hang

Tags: javascript, perl, mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

While working with Perl Mechanize Firefox I am trying to download a file by clicking an image on page I can see file getting downloaded in browser but script gets hanged in the console and does not proceed.

This is my code :

```
$click_here=$mech->xpath('//*[@src="../WRQualtricsControlPanel/CPGraphics/ExportCSV.2253945.gif"]',single => 1);
$mech->click($click_here);
```

this however downloads the file but script remains stuck here.

kindly help me to get through this.